# Jackson Visibility Jersey JAX-RS

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a JAX-RS provider for Jackson disable all the visibility options but for some reason jackson is still decoding the options.

```
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getDeserializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));

    mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
            .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE));
```

I need explicitly disable the Deserialization using @JsonIgnore. 
The only way to make the ID readonly is using JsonIgnore every where.

Example:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
@JsonIgnore()
private String id;

@JsonProperty(value = "id")
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@JsonIgnore()
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?